# Switch from unauth to developer authenticated cognito user - AWS iOS SDK

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

**Overall Problem:**
I have a problem using a developer authenticated identity with my front end (iOS). I know my backend produces the correct token and identityID but my refresh method never gets called. I've also looked at the sample but I get slightly confused with everything going on. 
**Flow Explanation:**
Currently I have a login screen that has a login button. The user presses the login button, then my api class takes the credentials, encrypts the password and stores it in keychain (commented out for now since it doesn't work on simulator). My DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider is called my app BusytimeAuthenticated. I have completed all the methods (I'm using AWS lambda and DynamoDB to authenticate users so) I start with unauthenticated access which allows me to access only two methods, login and signup. Then I want to assume my authenticated user which allows me to call my other methods.

my API Code:

```
[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;
id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[BusytimeAuthenticated alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                                          identityId:nil
                                                                                identityPoolId:@"SOMEIDENTITYPOOLID"
                                                                                logins:@{@"SOMEPROVIDERNAME": @"SOMEUSERNAME"}
                                                                                       providerName:@"SOMEPROVIDERNAME"
                                                                                                          ];

credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                    identityProvider:identityProvider
                                                                       unauthRoleArn:nil
                                                                         authRoleArn:nil];

configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                     credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
[[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
    [self testAuth];
    return nil;
}];
```

my DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider code (BusytimeAuthenticated) :

```
#import "BusytimeAuthenticated.h"

@interface BusytimeAuthenticated()
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *providerName;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString *token;
@end

@implementation BusytimeAuthenticated
@synthesize providerName=_providerName;
@synthesize token=_token;



- (instancetype)initWithRegionType:(AWSRegionType)regionType
                        identityId:(NSString *)identityId
                    identityPoolId:(NSString *)identityPoolId
                            logins:(NSDictionary *)logins
                      providerName:(NSString *)providerName{
    if (self = [super initWithRegionType:regionType identityId:identityId accountId:nil identityPoolId:identityPoolId logins:logins]) {
        self.providerName = providerName;
    }
    return self;
}

// Return the developer provider name which you choose while setting up the
// identity pool in the Amazon Cognito Console

- (BOOL)authenticatedWithProvider {
    return [self.logins objectForKey:self.providerName] != nil;
}


// If the app has a valid identityId return it, otherwise get a valid
// identityId from your backend.

- (BFTask *)getIdentityId {
    // already cached the identity id, return it
    if (self.identityId) {
        return [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];
    }
    // not authenticated with our developer provider
    else if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
        return [super getIdentityId];

    }
    // authenticated with our developer provider, use refresh logic to get id/token pair
    else {
        return [[BFTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (!self.identityId) {
                return [self refresh];
            }
            return [BFTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
        }];
    }

}


// Use the refresh method to communicate with your backend to get an
// identityId and token.

- (BFTask *)refresh {
    if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
        return [super getIdentityId];
    }else{
//        KeychainWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainWrapper alloc]init];
        AWSLambdaInvoker *lambdaInvoker = [AWSLambdaInvoker defaultLambdaInvoker];
        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : @"SOMEUSERNAME",
                                     @"password":@"SOMEENCRYPTEDPASS",
                                     @"isError" : @NO};
        NSLog(@"Here");
        [[lambdaInvoker invokeFunction:@"login" JSONObject:parameters] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask* task) {
            if (task.error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
            }
            if (task.exception) {
                NSLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);
            }
            if (task.result) {
                self.identityId = [task.result objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ];
                self.token = [task.result objectForKey:@"Token" ];
//                [keychain mySetObject:[task.result objectForKey:@"Token" ] forKey:@"Token"];
//                [keychain mySetObject:[task.result objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ] forKey:@"IdentityId"];
                NSLog(@"Result: %@", task.result);

            }
            return [BFTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
        }];



    }
    return NULL;
}

@end
```

**Summary Problem:**
Unfortunately when I test my new priveleges, I see from the error: "Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction". Clearly I'm not switching properly. I've placed a breakpoint in my refresh method to see if it's getting called. It's not. I'm not quite understanding how I switch properly. Any help with getting this to work is much appreciated.

Note: One big change I did make though is I took out the "DeveloperAuthenticationClient" class because I assumed I could do it without it.

Comment: My question has been updated to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205271/unauthenticated-user-to-authenticated-user-on-aws-cognito/33219337#33219337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are trying to call a Lambda function (which requires credentials) to get credentials. Because you are using the "default" client configuration, when your developer authenticated client comes back with a response it is going to override the credentials used to access your Lambda function. Additionally, once that id has been transitioned to authenticated, you won't be able to use it to get credentials in an unauth flow and would need to generate a new unauthenticated id just to authenticate again and then get back to your authenticated id.

I would strongly encourage you to setup [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of your Lambda function to remove this circular dependency.

Comment: Yes you are correct, Please take a look at my new flow: I instantiate my user with unauthenticated credentials. If the credentialsprovider has no logins set:     if (![credentialsProvider logins]){
I make the call directly to my backend to authenticate my user. If it all works out, then I authenticate my user with authenticated credentials. I also gave my authenticated credentials access to my login method as it that's the method that returns the identityID and token.

Comment: If the logins are set, then I just refresh my credentialsProvider

Comment: @user2977578 Again, you would have to maintain 2 different identities. You are creating more work for yourself. I strongly encourage you to not continue down this path.

Comment: Basically, both unauth and auth roles can call login. I use unauth first to call login. If that works, I set my credenitals provider to my developer auth identity class.

Comment: I will look into api gateway, but if it already works now does it matter? by 2 different identities, do you mean the unauth user and the auth user?

Comment: Regardless, outside of my refresh method I still have to check if the user provides correct credentials so I use my unauthenticated user for that. Then regardless, my unauthenticated user should be providing correct credentials in return for the identityId and token. So I don't see how api gateway makes it easier?

Comment: the refresh flow doesn't allow for a check to see if the user provided apt credentials, so I need to do this before I even set the credentials provider with the developer auth identity class

Comment: Is that why I recieve this error sometimes?    Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 9.)" UserInfo=0x7fa46b41b2d0 {__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to Identity 'us-east-1:96b5a862-4f5b-4399-80a3-71e92cfd8ac9' is forbidden.}

Comment: it gets fixed whenever I go into the identity browser and delete the identities in there?

Comment: I took up your suggestion, if you can please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228309/cognito-authentication-working-but-errors-show

Answer (score 0):

*Update based on new information in the question...*
A few things here:
1. Avoid code like `while(!finished)` to wait on an async task to complete. In the best case, this style of busy waiting will consume a CPU/core at 100% while doing nothing useful and adversely affect battery life and will only hurt performance of your app. Instead, use a notification with a block. Since you have already have a `AWSTask` in this instance, instead of returning `nil` at the end of the `[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock...` just call your `[self testAuth]` right there and do away with the finished/while code.
2. In your `getIdentityId` implementation the first if condition checks if there is an identityId and if there *is* it returns `nil`. I'm guessing you goal here is to cache the identityId after a successful authentication and return that so that you don't have to call your backend every time getIdentityId is called. If that is the case, pretty sure you want to return `identityId` instead of `nil`
3. I don't think this is the cause of your issue but will simplify things: As long as you've configured your identity pool with Auth/UnAuth roles in the console, you don't have to explicitly use them when initializing the `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider`.

Once these are resolved if you continue to have problems, please debug the code in more detail and tell us things like the following: 
Does the refresh method get called? If so, which parts of your if statement does it enter and what is the result? Does it ever enter the else block and call your backend identity provider? Does it successfully retrieve an identity id and return it?

If you get further but start experiencing a slightly different issue then please mark this question answered and post a separate question instead of continuing to edit this question. This will help keep things clear (this question/answer is getting pretty long and has changed).

---

*Original answer to initial posted question/code...* The [getIdentity method of the AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/getIdentityId) returns an [AWSTask](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/0c3a311c796cb1c231dedecbcf9f3f86500043ba/AWSCore/Bolts/AWSTask.h) (i.e. a [BFTask](https://boltsframework.github.io/docs/ios/Classes/BFTask.html)). So you'll need to call something like [continueWithBlock](https://boltsframework.github.io/docs/ios/Classes/BFTask.html#//api/name/continueWithBlock:) in order to actually execute the method. In the first block of code above it looks like you're not doing that.

Comment: When I added it in, I got weirder errors than before. Previously it was somewhat working when I called [credentialsProvider refresh] because it would enter my refresh method. Now when I added that in, I get this error: Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSLambdaInvokerErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSLambdaInvokerErrorDomain error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7f844d0f7ef0 {errorMessage=Task timed out after 3.00 seconds, com.amazonaws.AWSLambdaInvokerFunctionErrorKey=Unhandled}

Comment: One sec, let me figure something out. It's still entering my method with the continueWithBlock.

Comment: That looks like an error from the lambda function. See what the code is and that might give you a clue: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Constants/AWSLambdaErrorType.html You could also look into Cloud Trails logging from the lambda function.

Comment: edited my code, now my testAuth method (calls an authenticated lambda method) isn't even being called?

Comment: yeah I just fixed my lambda method, I was attempting to pass in my unauthenticated identityId but it didn't help.

Comment: BusyTime[14693:6974478] Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 9.)" UserInfo=0x7fe761fded10 {__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to Identity 'SOMEAUTHENTICATEDARN' is forbidden.}

Comment: no it's returning my token and id. I deleted a bunch of random identities (probably from passing in my unauthenticated identity id) in the cognito console and it started working. HOWEVER, the problem persists and I'm still in my unauth role

Comment: I've made these changes, my refresh method still gets entered and I still get the same error: Message=User: arn:aws:sts::445291524102:assumed-role/Cognito_BusyTimeUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:445291524102:function:deleteFriend, StatusCode=403, responseDataSize=238}

Comment: because of this, this question is still not answered. I can continue it in a new thread, but I can't mark it answered as the error hasn't changed.

Comment: Please provide the XCode output window that is traced after you click the button to authenticate with your DevAuth provider. You should see the requests from the CredentialProvider to the Cognito service being traced out there and any errors that occurring (be sure to obfuscate any secretkey or other sensitive values from the output). Make sure the identtiyid is the same one you return from your DevAuth provider.

Comment: please take a look at the new thread of my concern. I already saw you edit one of the guys' answer there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205271/unauthenticated-user-to-authenticated-user-on-aws-cognito/33219337#33219337

Comment: Is there some way that I mark this answer as updated on a new thread?