# Unauthenticated user to authenticated user on AWS Cognito

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My code is here: [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197019/switch-from-unauth-to-developer-authenticated-cognito-user-aws-ios-sdk)
Reposted because I wanted to ask a more direct question. How do I switch between unauthenticated user and authenticated? My unauthenticated seems cached and I've used these methods:

```
[credentialsProvider clearCredentials];
[credentialsProvider clearKeychain];
```

before the rest of my api code and it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

Note: I know it's not working because I make a call using lambda right after I switch up my configuration/credentials provider and only authorized users should be able to call this method.

EDIT @behrooziAWS answer:

API CODE:

```
 id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[DeveloperIdentityProviderClass alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                                          identityId:nil
                                                                                identityPoolId:@"SOMEIDENTITYPOOLID"
                                                                                logins:@{@"MYIDENTITYPROVIDERNAME": @"MYUSERNAME"}
                                                                                       providerName:@"MYIDENTITYPROVIDERNAME"
                                                                                                    ];
[credentialsProvider setIdentityProvider:identityProvider];
[credentialsProvider setLogins:@{@"MYIDENTITYPROVIDERNAME": @"MYUSERNAME"}];

[[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
    [self testAuth];
    return [BFTask taskWithResult:nil];
}];
```

Full Error: 
BusyTime[27043:7097936] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:87 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [{"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}]
2015-10-20 08:51:17.280 BusyTime[27043:7097936] Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSLambdaErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. UnrecognizedClientException" UserInfo=0x7ff27ab41150 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=UnrecognizedClientException, responseStatusCode=403, message=The security token included in the request is invalid., responseHeaders={type = immutable dict, count = 6,

IMPORTANT EDIT: I've hardcoded my refresh to use a working token and identityId. so:

```
self.identityId = @"someID";
self.token = @"someToken";
return [super getIdentityId];
```

and then ALL my code is working. But obviously this isn't sustainable, I need to be able to make a call to aws lambda to refresh my credentials. But when I set my identity provider, and set my login, I think it's changing me to my authenticated version, but I need to be in unauthenticated to call aws lambda. **Please refer to my code link above** and take a look at my refresh method to understand what I'm poorly trying to describe. Also please let me know if this should go in a new thread as this is a slightly different question. Not so familiar with stackoverflow's policies on questions.

Another error: [{"Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::445291524102:assumed-role/Cognito_BusyTimeAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:445291524102:function:login"}], SO now I'm assuming my auth provider for my refresh which is incorrect login flow. I'm thinking that I switch this up so that I login in my API class. When I return my identity ID and token, I save them to keychain. Finally, I use the above API code to switch my logins and in my refresh method, I simply return what I found in my keychain. The only problem is I'm not sure if this flow is correct because it doesnt actually "refresh" as I'm not calling my backend. I was wondering if I could wrap the refresh by changing back and forth from my unauth role to my auth role but this seems messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[credentialsProvder clearKeychain]` will clear the identityId, credentials and any logins, so clearCredentials is unnecessary: [clearKeychain Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/clearKeychain)

Normally you don't want to clear your identity id when you transition to an authenticated user.  If you simply add your provider and valid login token to the logins map and call `[credentialsProvider refresh]`, you will become authenticated with the same identity id.  From that point forward, you will only be able to access that identity if you provide a valid login token.  If you want to switch identities by logging out and then login as a authenticated user, that is when you use `clearKeychain`.

Comment: I get this error then when I'm trying to refresh with AWS Lambda. {"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}
I THINK it's because when I update my logins and identity provider and call refresh, it supposes that I'm an authenticated user, but only my unauthenticated user can call login/signup. I'll update my api code above now for you to see and show a full error.

Comment: I'm going to create a new thread, you've answered my question.

Comment: This answer should be known more.