# Cognito Authentication working but errors show?

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-cognito

Basically I'm using a developer authenticated identity to authenticate my users. Even though this error is showing:

> AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:87 |
>   -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:]
>   | Response body:
>   [{"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"Please provide a
>   valid public provider"}] 2015-10-20 17:50:19.251
>   BusyTime[56549:7365231] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m
>   line:435 | __73-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
>   getCredentialsWithCognito:authenticated:]_block_invoke |
>   GetCredentialsForIdentity failed. Error is [Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=7 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 7.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7f9d9342dde0 {__type=InvalidParameterException,
>   message=Please provide a valid public provider}]

Though this error shows, I'm still returning my identityId and Token and successfully invoking a lambda method that requires authenticated privileges to call. I believe it has something to do with my refresh method but I'm not exactly sure. Please help me deal with this error.

**my credentials provider code:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;
    id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[BusytimeAuthenticated alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                             identityId:nil
                                                                                         identityPoolId:@"EXAMPLEPOOLID"
                                                                                logins:@{@"login.busytimeapp": [defaults objectForKey:@"username"]}
                                                                                           providerName:@"login.busytimeapp"
                                                       ];

    credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                   identityProvider:identityProvider
                                                                      unauthRoleArn:nil
                                                                        authRoleArn:nil];

    configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
    [[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
        [self testAuth];
        return nil;
    }];
```

My Refresh method:

```
- (BFTask *)refresh {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
        return [super getIdentityId];
    }else{
        NSDictionary *post = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
                              [defaults objectForKey:@"password"], @"password",
                              nil];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SOMEURL"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        __block BOOL isLogged = false;
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                    options:0
                                                                      error:&error];
            isLogged = true;
            if(!newJSON){
                NSLog(@"DID NOT AUTHENTICATE");
            }else{

            self.identityId = [newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ];
            self.token = [newJSON objectForKey:@"Token" ];
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", newJSON);
            }

        }] resume];

        return [super getIdentityId];

    }
    return [super getIdentityId];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing the login provider name in the logins map as key. You can't do that for Developer Authenticated Identities.

Instead you should use the Cognito identity provider name, *cognito-identity.amazonaws.com*, in the map, like it says in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/). This should fix you exception.

Comment: Can you give me an example via code? I'm a little confused with that

Comment: if you meant like this: logins:@{@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com": [defaults objectForKey:@"username"]}  when I switch it I get this error:  AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:534 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke350 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 9.)" UserInfo=0x7fc7084f7ed0 {__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Invalid login token.}]

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

The error states, "Invalid login token", which means the token you are passing in logins map is invalid. This token should be the token vended by you backend which are generated by a Cognito API called GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. You have to call this API from your backend with your AWS developer credentials.

Comment: Thanks, it works with this code: logins:@{@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com": [defaults objectForKey:@"Token"]}
                                                                                           providerName:@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"

Comment: what's the purpose of setting up login.busytimeapp though?