# AWS API Gateway unreliability in refresh

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I was using API gateway for quite a bit and I only slightly changed the api to allow another function. I went into api gateway and tested the function to make sure it worked. Then I tried it on my iPhone and it worked as well. Randomly later, I started getting repeated instances of {errorMessage: "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"}. I don't understand why a simple login method (the method in API Gateway) would timeout ever, especially since I tested the input both on the iPhone (when it was previously working) and directly with the api gateway console.

*Comment*: I'm not utilizing the generated sdk or the AWSAPIGatewayClient. I'm simply making an http request.

*http request to login*

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary *post = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
                      [defaults objectForKey:@"password"], @"password",
                      nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someLoginEndpoint"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                            options:0
                                                              error:&error];
    if(!newJSON || [newJSON objectForKey:@"errorMessage"]){
        NSLog(@"%@",newJSON);
        callBack(false);
        NSLog(@"DID NOT AUTHENTICATE");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",newJSON);
        [defaults setValue:[newJSON objectForKey:@"Token"] forKey:@"Token"];
        [defaults setValue:[newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId"] forKey:@"IdentityId"];
        [self authenticateUser:^(BOOL call){
            callBack(call);
        }];
    }
}] resume];
```

*Refresh method*

```
- (AWSTask *)refresh {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![self authenticatedWithProvider]) {
    return [super getIdentityId];
}else{
    NSDictionary *post = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
                          [defaults objectForKey:@"password"], @"password",
                          nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someLoginEndpoint"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    __block BOOL isLogged = false;

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:&error];
        isLogged = true;
        if(!newJSON){
            NSLog(@"DID NOT AUTHENTICATE");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"The IdentityID in the refresh method: %@",[newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ]);
            NSLog(@"The token in the refresh method: %@",[newJSON objectForKey:@"Token" ]);
        self.identityId = [newJSON objectForKey:@"IdentityId" ];
        self.token = [newJSON objectForKey:@"Token" ];
        }

    }] resume];

    return [super getIdentityId];

}
return [super getIdentityId];
}
```

*authenticate user*

```
 //BusytimeAuthenticated
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id<AWSCognitoIdentityProvider> identityProvider = [[BusytimeAuthenticated alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                         identityId:nil
                                                                                     identityPoolId:@"somePoolID"
                                                                            logins:@{@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com": [defaults objectForKey:@"Token"]}
                                                                                       providerName:@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
                                                   ];

credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                               identityProvider:identityProvider
                                                                  unauthRoleArn:nil
                                                                    authRoleArn:nil];
configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                            credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
[[credentialsProvider refresh] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task){
    callBack(true);
    return nil;
}];
```

}

*error*
Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={message=Invalid login token. Can't pass in a Cognito token., __type=NotAuthorizedException}]

**My basic question** is, why is this operation being so unreliable? It occasionally works to login my user and then when I use the refresh method, I pass in the same credentials but the side-by-side request causes the second request to fail.

Comment: Are you using a Lambda integration? Lambda cold start may cause your API Gateway call to time out, you may need to optimized your Lambda to avoid timeouts. Also, you've only included your refresh method. The Cognito error would seem to indicate a problem with the way you've coded your identity provider. You may want to update your question with the full identity provider implementation.

Comment: give me a second, I'll update my question. But yes I'm using lambda integration, I'll look into optimizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding timeouts:**

As mentioned in comments Lambda cold start may cause your API Gateway call to time out, you may need to optimized your Lambda to avoid timeouts.

**Regarding refresh error:**

You are using **cognito-identity.amazonaws.com** in the logins map, but using the IdentityProvider pattern for refresh. This is why the first authentication succeeds but attempts to refresh fail. The logic in your refresh will never fire.

I suggest you look at our [end-to-end sample](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) for suggested flow for handling developer authenticated identities.

If you want to continue to use **cognito-identity.amazonaws.com** in the logins map, then your token refresh would actually need to be handled *outside* of the identity/credentials provider, akin to the way you would handle Facebook tokens.

Comment: how do I optimize my lambda method? Should I just increase the timeout, or is there something specific to improve cold start time?

Comment: I was wondering if I could receive some clarification on the "regarding to refresh error" portion. I'm completely lost on how you think I should be approaching this. The sample app gets really confusing as it doesn't comment what it's doing as much as other portions within the refresh method.

Comment: Also I was on stack overflow a while ago and I was facing several problems with developer authenticated identities, and I was told to switch from my "MyProviderName" to "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com".

Comment: this is the question where I was recommended to switch from "MyProviderName": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228309/cognito-authentication-working-but-errors-show

Comment: Using cognito-identity.amazonaws.com works if you are not using the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider pattern. You may want to look at [this forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=685904&#685904), it should hopefully clarify the intended flow with this pattern.